# Extract public key from a weak client

Tags: ssl, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

Let's say we have a client that uses asymmetric cryptography to communicate with a server. This could be SSL or just a custom encryption.

Now if we assume that the client's source code is easy to disassemble, can we extract the public key and hence send bogus messages to the server?
Anyway to avoid this? Consider that it is really hard to keep the client's source code safe.

Comment: TLS does not work like you think it does. A client can have a certificate, but the encryption keys used to protect a given TLS exchange are not the ones in the certificate. If you are able to get access to the certificate (which is typically not bundled with the source code) **AND** the associated private key then of course you can impersonate the client to any server. Which is why the private key must be protected.

Comment: @Farshid Are you talking about a SSL/TLS connection with or without required certificate based client authentication?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I did perhaps misunderstood TLS as I study it very briefly. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the keys that protect the TLS exchange are not in the certificate. How does the encryption happen if we don't use those keys at some point?

Comment: @Robert In practice I am looking at a socket connection secured with SSL/TLS but because this bring down the latency of the connection I prefer to enable it in the client only when needed and disable it for low latency connections.

Comment: The keys are computed during the exchange. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake for a primer. In modern versions of TLS only ephemeral keys are used, so keys in certificate are only used to authenticate, not to encrypt anything. You can fully have a TLS exchange without any certificate whatsoever.